# Not able to override Bootstrap in Angular 7 app

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, sass, angular7

In Angular App, I am trying to override my `breadcrumb` style by removing the divider. I use `https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/breadcrumb/#example`.  But it is not working.

Here is my angular.json file script

```
    {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ibo": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/ibo",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                "includePaths": [
                  "node_modules/bootstrap",
                  "src/styles"
                ]
             },
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ],
            "styles": [
               "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
               "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
               "src/styles/styles.scss",
            ],
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ibo:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ibo:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ibo:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "ibo-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "ibo:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "ibo:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "ibo"
}
```

my style.scss:

```
    @import '~bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss';
    @import '~bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss';
    @import '~bootstrap/scss/mixins/_breakpoints.scss';
    @import 'global.scss';
    
    $grid-breakpoints: (
        sm: 768px,
        md: 768px,
        lg: 1024px
    );
    
    $container-min-widths: (
      sm: 768px,
      md: 768px,
      lg: 1024px
    );
    
    //resets;-
    
    
    
    html,body{
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .wrapper.container-fluid{
        min-height: 100%;
        padding:0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    
    $breadcrumb-divider: none !important;
```

Any one can help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try adding `!important` maybe it helps

Comment: @JohnVelasquez - but doc not say that. still tried, not works

Comment: did you import this to your `styles.scss`?

Comment: try moving your `$breadcrumb-divider` variable to the first line

Comment: @JohnVelasquez - from where you want me to remove?

Comment: move your `$breadcrumb-divider` at the very top

Comment: Ok, then where can i add it?

Comment: move it at the very top of your `style.scss`, `$breadcrumb-divider` must be the first line code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. remove `bootstrap.min.css` from angular.json.

   ```
   ....
   "styles": [
      "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
      "src/styles/styles.scss",
   ],
   ....
   ```
2. import `bootstrap.scss` file.

   ```
   @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
   ```
3. set `$breadcrumb-divider` before `@import` statements.

   ```
   $breadcrumb-divider: none;

   @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
   ...
   ```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of importing or using CDN for bootstrap styles, load bootstrap.css using angular.json as below. Order should be first bootstrap.css and then style.css

```
"styles": [
             "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
             "src/styles/styles.scss",
          ],
```

you can use below css to override divider. This will not override bootstrap variable.

```
.breadcrumb>li+li:before { 
    padding: 0 5px; 
    color: #ccc; 
    content: ""; 
}
```

To Override bootstrap variable put "$breadcrumb-divider: none;" at the top of style.scss.

Comment: what about this `@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"; ` I am already importing in the app `style.scss` only right?

Comment: You can remove it

Comment: removed and added like your suggestion, no luck!!

Comment: Could you please update question what you have tried.... Also rerun ng serve command after updating angular.json file

Comment: yes, I restarted my app after `package.json` updated

Comment: Here you are trying to update variable from bootstrap. So put this code in style.css. 
 %scope {
  @import '~bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss';

$breadcrumb-divider: none !global;
}

Comment: .breadcrumb>li+li:before {
  padding: 0 5px;
  color: #ccc;
  content: "";
}

Comment: works... but why we can't able to override the variable?

Comment: $breadcrumb-divider: none this line must be first line in style.scss. This is what i have read in some blogs. you can try this also.

Comment: Thank you so much it was my problem ! Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

**Two simple steps for the latest angular version**

1). In angular.json file, add your custom stylesheet after bootstrap related stylesheet like I have added in my code snippet

```
"styles": [
    "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "src/styles.css"
 ],
```

2). At the end run again your application manually using `ng serve` command

Answer (score 0):

1. Open `angular.json`
2. Change `"extractCss": true` to `"extractCss": false` should fixes the issue